# How does "newElements" work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : "div.navigation",
        nextSelector : "div.next-page a:first",   
        itemSelector : "#posts-container div.post",
        bufferPx     : 80
        },
        function( newElements ) {
            var $newElems = $ ( newElements );
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
        }
);
```

While implementing `infiniteScroll` plugin, I used `newElements` without actually knowing what it really is. In the presented code, I passed `newElements` in as a parameter but it wasn't declared anywhere above. However, the function works fine; new posts elements are stored in `$newElems`.

When I use `newElements`, am I conveniently calling all the newly added elements to the DOM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`newelements` isn't anything in JavaScript. It's a variable that is passed to the callback function when new items are loaded.

You should probably read over the documentation of InfiniteScroll, which clearly details this function:

```
function(arrayOfNewElems){

     // optional callback when new content is successfully loaded in.

     // keyword `this` will refer to the new DOM content that was just added.
     // as of 1.5, `this` matches the element you called the plugin on (e.g. #content)
     //                   all the new elements that were found are passed in as an array
}
```

You could assign any name to the callback parameter, but it will contain an array of the new elements.

Comment: As I am much more familiar with JavaScript than when I asked this question, I get it now. When `infinitescroll` loads new content, it automatically passes the new content as an argument to an optional callback function, `function(newElements) { ... }`. Since `newElements` is just a parameter name, it can be anything such as `loadedElements`, `newContent`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, read the documentation of this plugin: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

As you can see, the comments on the callback function describe:

```
function(arrayOfNewElems){
    // optional callback when new content is successfully loaded in.

    // keyword `this` will refer to the new DOM content that was just added.
    // as of 1.5, `this` matches the element you called the plugin on (e.g. #content)
    // all the new elements that were found are passed in as an array
}
```

This means, the newElements parameter of your callback function does actually contain (an array of) all the newly added elements.

The reason that newElements does not have to be declared before, is that it is a function argument. More on functions can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: Why not upvote the answer already posted? Also, please, please don't reference W3Schools in your answers... http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Because it hadn't been posted yet when I wrote mine :)